# Editing and saving any Inbox mail item in Outlook creates 1 more mail

Tags: outlook-addin

When I double-click and open any mail in Outlook 2013, there is an option to Edit the message in "Actions".
When I edit the message and save it, Outlook creates 1 more mail item.
Now, there are 2 mail items in Inbox.

Why does Outlook create another mail?
It happens the same if I save the mail item programmatically.

Is there a way I can find out which is the newly mail item and then delete the same?

Comment: Is that an IMAP4 account? It is know to have problems like that.

Comment: Yes, it is an IMAP account. Thanks for the information.

Comment: IMAP4 provider is the worst - it is known to create dupes when modifying an item. I don't think there is anything you can do...

Comment: OK. Thanks for the information Dmitry.